# Prefix increment operator error C++

Tags: c++, prefix, postfix-operator

I'm guessing it's to do with precedence but why is this legal

```
vector<string>::iterator iter = vec.begin();
iter++->empty();
```

But this is not.

```
vector<string>::iterator iter = vec.begin();
++iter->empty();
```

Can someone try to explain the chain of event that happen here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow operator has higher precedence than increment, so `++iter->empty()` is parsed as `++(iter->empty())`, not `(++iter)->empty()`. The post-increment version works because there's only one way to parse `iter++->empty()`.